# Can you have two instances of a program to one database on a network

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, vbscript

Hey guys this might a simple question to answer but  currently im clueless, i need to develop a application in visual studio 2012 using visual basics (window forms) and connect it to a database on a sql server 2008 R2 on a network. The application is also suppose to be able to run on multiple machines and connect to the single database to run multiple sql transactions. So the question is, is this possible and is there a unique way of developing this application, or a different approach entirely with multiple databases.

Comment: Could you please focus on a specific question? Currently, the subject is too broad to answer ("is there a unique way of developing this application").

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but of course you should use one database.

Comment: Well my main concern here is can i make a application that can run simultaneously on two different machines accessing the same database but different tables without a issue.

Comment: Yes. This applications can actually access the same tables without an issue. Don't forget about transactions.

Comment: Thank you just wanted to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a WinForms client running on multiple machines connected to a single SQL Server database is a normal and expected configuration.  SQL Server (and a database in general) is meant to serve the needs to multiple users.

It is also very common for multiple users to be working on items that will affect the same tables inside a common database.  Once data is retrieved from the database, the connection between the WinForms client and the database would be severed.  When a user wants to commit modified rows to the shared database, a new connection would be established to update the modified records, remove any records marked for deletion, or create new records requested by the WinForms client.